# Storing an image from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Basically what I'm trying to do is take an image from Parse and store it in a variable, which I can then set to an image view in a tableViewCell.

I can't figure out how to store the images once I get them from Parse.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

class YourEvents: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var currentuser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username


    //array
    var testArray = [String]()

    var testdecr = [String]()

    var imagestored = UIImage()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var query = PFQuery(className:"Companies")
         let pUserName = PFUser.currentUser()?["username"] as? String

        query.whereKey("createdby", equalTo:"\(pUserName)")
        // let runkey = query.orderByAscending("companyname")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                //do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                    for object in objects {

                        let load = object.objectForKey("companyname") as! String
                        self.testArray .append(load)

                        print(self.testArray)

                        let load2 = object.objectForKey("companydescription") as! String
                        self.testdecr.append(load2)

                        print(self.testdecr)

                        //let images: PFFile = object["imagefile"] as! PFFile

                     if let userPicture = ["picture"] as? PFFile {
                        userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if (error == nil) {
                                self.imagestored.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }

                }
            } else {
                //log details of failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error?.userInfo) ")

            }


        }

        // reload  UIViewController and UITabkeView
        sleep(3)

        do_table_refresh()
    }

    func do_table_refresh () {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),  {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return testArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourstartups", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourStartupsCell
        cell.lbTitle!.text = self.testArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbDescription!.text = self.testdecr[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

[image: my code]

Comment: have you looked at using `PFImageView` ?

Comment: Xcode doesn't seem to  recognise that. http://postimg.org/image/nyvzwgs89/

Answer (score 0):

Using PFImageView instead of UIImageView makes it less cumbersome to work with files from Parse.  Parse will handle caching the image for faster retrieval as well as provide you methods to set a placeholder image for instance or to perform any work after the image has been retrieved.

Here's an example where imageView is of type PFImageView. Just don't forget to import ParseUI as well.

```
let file = object["picture"] as? PFFile;
imageView.file = file 
imageView.image = .... //set placeholder image
imageView.loadInBackground(nil) //will asynchronously download the image if not cached
```

Comment: That gets these errors:  Value of type 'UIImage' has no member 'file' and  Value of type 'UIImage' has no member 'image' http://postimg.org/image/u84o6wrgj/

Comment: well my advice was if you want this image to appear on screen, instead of using UIImageView, use PFImageView instead and just set its properties like the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken the object as `UIImage`

```
var imagestored = UIImage()
```

and then you are accessing that object as `UIImageView`

```
self.imagestored.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
```

thats why you are getting that error.Store the image directly to that variable like this

```
self.imagestored = UIImage(data:imageData)
```

That will solve your problem.

Comment: This works but then I have another error:  Type 'UIImage' has no subscript members http://postimg.org/image/ilj9oj9st/

Comment: you're issue is imageStore is an image. So there's no image property. You just set imageStore equal to the image.

Answer (score 0):

the error is there:

```
self.imagestored.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
```

try to replace it with:

```
self.imagestored = UIImage(data:imageData)
```